# Set up PHP server for public access

Tags: php, client-server

I'm new to PHP but I can't find good examples - mostly they are for local setups or advanced stuff.  I created a PHP page on an EC2 server.  It works fine when accessing it locally, however, what do I need to do to make it publically accessible from a different network?  Can this work from both Apache and IIS?

Answer (score 0):

For ec2 you have to make sure you open up port 80 in your dashboard. "Security Groups"